# Unable to Remove 'Left Quote' Character (`) from Column names

Tags: r

I am experiencing problems removing the left quote " ` " character (acute, back quote, grave, grave accent, open quote, or a push are alternative names) from some of my column names.

I attempted several of the solutions provided on these pages (in code below) but with no success.  Thoughts?

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)


tibble_dog <- tibble (`yls23_rolled_/_nktg23_`   = 1:6,
                      `1alw23_rolled_/_ndatg23_` = 11:16,
                      `1alw6_rolled_/_ndatg24_`  = 21:26
                      )

tibble_dog


tibble_dog <- tibble_dog %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_remove(., " ` "), everything())

tibble_dog

names(tibble_dog) <- sub("`", "", names(tibble_dog))

tibble_dog

names(tibble_dog) <- trimws(colnames(tibble_dog), whitespace = "\\s+\\(.*")

tibble_dog
```

Comment: The reason you *see* the backtick `\`` in the column names is because tibbles wrap column names in backticks where the name contains normally "illegal" characters (the slash `/` is the problem). Try `tibble("a b"=1)` and `tibble("a/b"=1)` and `tibble("a_b"=1)` to see what I'm talking about. The backticks are not really in the column name.

Comment: You are absolutely correct!  For some reason, my once working random forest modeling code ceased to recognize these new added columns containing the backslash.  My thought was that I needed to remove the 'left quote' characters.  I think I need to do that.  I'll simply eliminate the backslash character.  Killer observation.  For some reason,  the page does not allow me the ability to select this as the solution, which it is, so I will instead click the "up arrow."  Thanks for your keen eye.

Answer (score 2):

you could try the `clean_names` function from the janitor package:

```
library(janitor)

janitor::clean_names(tibble_dog)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the comments ...

The reason you see the backtick `` ` `` in the column names is because tibbles wrap column names in backticks where the name contains normally "illegal" characters (the slash `/` is the problem). See:

```r
tibble("a b" = 1)
# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#   `a b`
#   <dbl>
# 1     1
tibble("a/b" = 1)
# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#   `a/b`
#   <dbl>
# 1     1
tibble("a_b" = 1)
# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#     a_b
#   <dbl>
# 1     1
```

Instead of trying to remove the backticks, you may consider removing the slash from the column names with

```r
names(tibble_dog) <- sub("/", "", names(tibble_dog))
```